# Session doesn't save value with redirect-> "with" method laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, session

When I put data like this:

```
$request->session()->put('123', '12345')
```

, session contains this value, but when I try to put data into session this way

```
$result = ['status' => 'Product has been updated']
return redirect('/admin/products/')->with($result);
```

Session doesn't contains it.

```
kernel:

    class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
         \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
         \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}

routes:

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'Admin\IndexController@index', 'as' => 'adminIndex']);
        Route::resource('/products', 'Admin\ProductController');
    });
```

I have red about changes in laravel 5.2 and that this problem may cause web middleware but i haven't it in my routes. Why session doesn't contain given status then?

Comment: deleted it cause problem was described very unclearly

Comment: Can you also include the `web` array in your `Kernel.php`?

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: Showed full kernel in the question

Comment: Try removing the `StartSession` and `ShareErrorsFromSession` from the `web` array of `$middlewareGroups` since you're starting it twice now.

Comment: woah, that helped! I guess until new bug appears ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Session::flash(key,value)` function to store data for retrieval once before performing a redirect.

```
Session::flash('123', '12345');
```

OR

```
session()->flash('123','12345');
return redirect('/admin/products/');
```

You can read these values later but only once, it will resolve your issue.

Comment: uh, flash expects 2 parameters and I have an array :c

Comment: You can simply `json_encode()` your array before flashing and decode it while reading.

Comment: @Batmannn you can do `Session::flash('status',$result["status"])` but I doubt it will work because `redirect()->with()` actually flashes data internally.